# VB.Net Image Encryption

Tags: vb.net, image, encryption

i'm making a program about encryption and i need to encrypt image in it.
is there a way i can do this in vb.net and how?

http://www.iaeng.org/IJCS/issues_v35/issue_1/IJCS_35_1_03.pdf

here is the layout sample
[image: layout sample]

Comment: So you want us to download a 9 page paper, read it and write an algorithm for you?  Not gonna happen.

Comment: @Plutonix i'm not asking for an algorithm, because there is an algorithm in the PDF. what i'm asking is if there is an equivalent code. for example(Page 2-3) `3: Get ImageWidth and ImageHeight ` how do i get imagewidth and imageheight using vb.net.

Comment: I must tell you something. There's this amazing thing called _Google_! Just type in what you need and it will most likely find it for you! https://www.google.com/search?q=VB.NET+Get+image+width+and+height

Comment: @VisualVincent wow! that was very helpful. thanks :) maybe i'll come back again after i've finished writing the codes.

Comment: Are you serious? Have you never heard about Google/Bing/etc.?

Comment: @VisualVincent i was joking. lol. haha. btw i've written the codes but only a few.